# Will Terragrunt remove my exisitng Cognito user accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When running `terragrunt plan` cmd after making some changes on the AWS Cognito config I get the following detail amongst the list of changes. Does it mean it will delete existing users? or is it fine to apply?

```
  ~ resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pool" {
      ~ estimated_number_of_users  = 0 -> 42
        id                         = "us-east-1_SaiB8Dezq"
      ~ last_modified_date         = "2023-02-09T17:07:37Z" -> "2023-07-11T11:59:30Z"
        name                       = "mailberry-users-prod"
        tags                       = {}
        # (12 unchanged attributes hidden)
```